# Logback with Spring MVC doesn't work

Tags: spring, maven, logging, slf4j, logback

I developed a webapp with Spring MVC and build it with maven. I want to improve logging using logback sl4j logging framework, but I'm completely new to it.
I modifide my pom.xml this way:

```
<!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <!--Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j--> 
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>   
<!-- Logging -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
  <version>${logback.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and then added the following lines to my custom exception DatabaseException:

```
    private final static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseException.class);
```

...

```
public DatabaseException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, cause.getMessage());
}
```

then I added under classpath logback.xml configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
    ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <logger name='org.springframework'>
    <level value='INFO' />
  </logger>



    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
      </root>

    </configuration>
```

So when I rise this exception I would logback to print to stdout some message BUT nothing.
When I deploy and run the app with tomcat it prints only container logs [talledContainer]-INFO ... etc etc and there is no trace of my logger and I don't figure out why, can you help me?

Comment: What is the full qualified name of the `Logger`? `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` or `org.slf4j.Logger`? Why you need to cast it?

Comment: Because without the cast it is qualified as slf4j.Logger and netbeans rise a compile error

Comment: @andPat please provide the relevant `import` statements to show what `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` you're using. Also, have you checked the output from Tomcat to ensure there aren't any slf4j setup warnings printed?